# Python NameError: global name 'any' is not defined

Tags: python, any

I am getting the following error on my production server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request)
 File "myproject/middleware.py", line 31, in process_request
if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):

NameError: global name 'any' is not defined
```

The server is running python 2.6 and in development this error was not raised. The offending code is in `middleware.py`:

```
...
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Should I rewrite this `any` function to work around the problem?

Comment: From the stack trace, your server appears to be running Python 2.4, which doesn't have `any`.

Comment: oops. Oh yeah. Any suggestions how can I rewrite the code to be compatible with python2.4?

Comment: @Ned seems to have given a good answer. Although I would really consider upgrading if at all possible. The next version of Django (1.4) won't support Python 2.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are actually running on Python 2.4, which doesn't have an `any` builtin.

If you need to define your own `any`, it's easy:

```
try:
    any
except NameError:
    def any(s):
        for v in s:
            if v:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

**I got this Python error as well with this line:**

```
>>> any([False, True, False])
Error:'any' is not defined
```

**Here's a work around without redefining the `any` function:**

```
>>> [False, True, False].count(True) > 0
True
```

Counting the number of Trues and then asserting it is greater than 0 does the same thing as the any function.  It might be slightly less efficient since it requires a full list scan rather than breaking out as soon as a True is found.