# Check value in dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
foob = {1:{'url':'www.abc.com', 'name':'abc'}, 2:{'url':'www.def.com', 'name':'def'}}
item = {'url':'www.abc.com', 'name':'wrong name'}

if item in foob.values():
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

I want to change `item in list.values()` so that it only compares `url` values and not whole dictionary. Is <strike>it possible to do that without iterating through whole dictionary</strike> there a simple way to do this without writing a separate for loop?

Comment: Iteration is the only choice, try converting it into some other structure like lists etc then you achieve your desired result but still that one is also a complex process.

Comment: Even `in` iterates the list behind the scenes…!

Comment: Yes it is, in any way you need Iterations.

Comment: Please, don't overwrite built-in functions. There's a `dict` built-in function, which is actually the dictionaries constructor, and is useful when copying dictionaries. If you call `dict({})' after your declaration, you're gonna have a surprise...

Comment: Also, you are using a dictionary, but if your keys are only successive integers, it's more than useless, and you should use a list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a generator expression:

```
if any(i['url'] == item['url'] for i in dict.values()):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: I can't use any somewhy, it works in Eclipse, but I am coding a plugin for Plex and in there I get `NameError: global name 'any' is not defined` and do not know why...

Comment: Quick googling fixed this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037821/python-nameerror-global-name-any-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work, but I don't think there is a way can avoid some kind of iterate.

```
dict = {1:{'url':'www.abc.com', 'name':'abc'}, 2:{'url':'www.def.com', 'name':'def'}}
item = {'url':'www.abc.com', 'name':'wrong name'}

if item['url'] in [i['url'] for i in dict.values()]:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

I agree deceze's code, use any

Comment: That's quite a wasteful way to do it.

Comment: @deceze please elaborate

Comment: @deceze You mean, besides the fact it redefines the `dict` built-in function?

Comment: @Valdas It iterates the whole list once to construct a new list to then iterate that again to check for the existence of the value.

Comment: The second snippet *always* prints "no"…